# What is a shaft collar called that is used to restrain a pulley?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design

I would like to look for a shaft collar like the one used in this photo of a cable robot:
[image]

As you can see, there is a flexure that clamps the collar onto the shaft (as a shaft collar does). In addition, there are two screw holes where the collar can secure to a pulley.

When shaft collar is typed into google you get an infinity of these, so clearly I don't have good search terms or the correct name for this type of component:  [image]

Comment: There is a variety of shaft collars. A good way to figure out names is McMaster, which has one of the best parts websites I can think of -- https://www.mcmaster.com/shaft-collars/construction~one-piece/?SrchEntryWebPart_InpBox=shaft+collar+   ... As NMech points out, the picture is also showing a flange feature, which may be the more unique feature in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for

- `mountable shaft collar with flange`
  or
- `flanged mount`